# Dependence of mobility of charge carriers in semiconductor on the applied electricfield

Tags: semiconductors

The mobility in a moderately doped semiconductor depends on the temperature, carrier concentration and the applied electric field. so I want to know:

1. How does mobility vary with electric field while the temperature and carrier concentration are kept constant?? Is there any empirical relation or a model that speaks about it?
2. Similarly how does the mobility vary with temperature (Apart from the lattice scattering and ionized impurity scattering phenomena)?

Please suggest any books that speak of these aspects in detail.

Answer (score 1):

1) The mobility versus the electric field behaves like the following graph:

[image: Effective and universal mobility versus electric field]

The black line is the effective mobility while the red line is the plot of the universal mobility. This is experimental data, so there might differ from calculations, but the tendencies are the same.

2) Mobility is mainly affected by:

1. Lattice scattering (phonons) (Sah et al)
2. Ionized impurity scattering (Caughey & Thomas)
3. Scattering by lattice imperfections (such as surface scattering) (Selberherr, Yamaguchi)
4. Carrier-carrier scattering (Dorkel & Leturcq)
5. Neutral impurity scattering
6. Velocity saturation by high electric fields (Sodini et al)

Some books which may help you are:

-*Quantum transport: Atom to transistor*, S. Datta

-*Electronic device architectures for the nano-CMOS era. From ultimate CMOS scaling to beyond CMOS devices*, Ferry, Goodnick, and Bird

-*Physical properties of semiconductors*, C.M. Wolfe

-*Semiconductor material and device characterization*, D.K. Schroder

-*Introduction to solid state physics*, C. Kittel